# Unit testing UrlHelper extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mstest

I have written several extension methods for the UrlHelper in my ASP.NET Core project. Now I would like to write unit tests for them. However, many of my extension methods leverage the UrlHelper's methods (for example, Action), so I need to pass a working UrlHelper to the `this` argument (or a working UrlHelper to call the methods on).

How can I instantiate a working UrlHelper? I tried this:

```
        Mock<HttpContext> mockHTTPContext = new Mock<HttpContext>();
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionContext actionContext = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionContext(
            new DefaultHttpContext(), 
            new RouteData(), 
            new ActionDescriptor());
        UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(actionContext);

        Guid theGUID = Guid.NewGuid();

        Assert.AreEqual("/Admin/Users/Edit/" + theGUID.ToString(), UrlHelperExtensions.UserEditPage(urlHelper, theGUID));
```

It crashes (`Test method Test.Commons.Admin.UrlHelperTests.URLGeneration threw exception: 
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index`) with this call stack:

```
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.UrlHelper.GetVirtualPathData(String routeName, RouteValueDictionary values)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.UrlHelper.Action(UrlActionContext actionContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.UrlHelperExtensions.Action(IUrlHelper helper, String action, String controller, Object values)
   at <MY PROEJCT>.UrlHelperExtensions.UserEditPage(IUrlHelper helper, Guid i_userGUID) 
   at <MY TEST>.URLGeneration()
```

An example of the extension methods is the following:

```
    public static string UserEditPage(this IUrlHelper helper, Guid i_userGUID)
    {
        return helper.Action(
            nameof(UsersController.EditUser), 
            "Users", 
            new { id = i_userGUID });
    }
```

Comment: Can you share one of the extension methods?

Comment: @ScottHannen I added one

Comment: All this extension does is call another extension - `Action`. So if you write a unit test for it, you're really just testing the `Action` extension, which isn't your code. That's not a problem with this extension. The extension makes the code more readable. But it's a "humble" method, meaning that it doesn't really do anything. That means there's possibly no point in trying to write a unit test for it. It would really just be a test for existing framework code.

Comment: @ScottHannen That is true for the method I posted as an example. But other methods may take several parameters, combine them, have conditional branches, call methods... so they would not be "humble" methods any more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet to test UrlHelper extensions would be to mock `IUrlHelper`, e.g. using Moq:

```
// arrange
UrlActionContext actual = null;
var userId = new Guid("52368a14-23fa-4c7f-a9e9-69b44fafcade");

// prepare action context as necessary
var actionContext = new ActionContext
{
    ActionDescriptor = new ActionDescriptor(),
    RouteData = new RouteData(),
};

// create url helper mock
var urlHelper = new Mock<IUrlHelper>();
urlHelper.SetupGet(h => h.ActionContext).Returns(actionContext);
urlHelper.Setup(h => h.Action(It.IsAny<UrlActionContext>()))
    .Callback((UrlActionContext context) => actual = context);

// act
var result = urlHelper.Object.UserEditPage(userId);

// assert
urlHelper.Verify();
Assert.Equal("EditUser", actual.Action);
Assert.Equal("Users", actual.Controller);
Assert.Null(actual.RouteName);

var values = new RouteValueDictionary(actual.Values);
Assert.Equal(userId, values["id"]);
```

Check out the [UrlHelperExtensionsTest](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/v2.2.4/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/test/Routing/UrlHelperExtensionsTest.cs) of ASP.NET Core to get some ideas on how this works in detail.

Comment: Thank you @poke, I've tried your suggestion, but I couldn't get it to work. I get an anonymous type as the type of `actual.Values`, and it stops there.

Comment: @Simone You can do `new RouteValueDictionary(actual.Values)` to create a new dictionary from the anonymous object which you can then perform your checks on. I’ve updated my answer for that.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it when I'm back in the office.